# Facing problem with "gtk.RESPONSE_OK" in the simple-player quickly tutorial

Tags: application-development, python, gtk, quickly

I am fairly new to both quickly and Python. I am facing several problems while learning to use quickly from the following tutorial on the Ubuntu developers site:
http://developer.ubuntu.com/resources/app-developer-cookbook/multimedia/creating-a-simple-media-player/

The following error I'm unable to understand:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sumit/Sumit/simple-player/simple_player/SimplePlayerWindow.py", line 36, in on_openbutton_clicked
    if response==gtk.RESPONSE_OK:
NameError: global name 'gtk' is not defined
```

I realize that I am supposed to import something, so I tried to add `import gtk` which it didn't work and it gave the following error:

```
  from gtk import _gtk
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:40: Warning: g_type_get_qdata: assertion `node != NULL' failed
  from gtk import _gtk
```

I have followed every step of the tutorials so far. But there is no mention of any other imports other that "prompts" and "os". Please help.

---

*Contribution of Agmenor, facing the same problem:*

I also tried to replace the text `if response == gtk.RESPONSE_OK:` by `if response == Gtk.RESPONSE_OK:` (notice the capital G). This gives another error:

```
AttributeError: 'gi.repository.Gtk' object has no attribute 'RESPONSE_OK'
```

Comment: "Didn't work" is somewhat the most useless thing to say. What happened when you did a "import gtk" at the top? Do you get another traceback? Some other error?

Comment: I answered that comment by editing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I replaced "gtk.RESPONSE_OK" with "Gtk.ResponseType.OK"

Now everything is working correctly.

Found it here:
http://python-gtk-3-tutorial.readthedocs.org/en/latest/dialogs.html

Comment: it seems like this is exactly what i originally suggested in my answer

Comment: Thank you sumit_gt. Please accept your own answer with the check sign. Aking1012, I share sumit_gt's likely opinion that your answer was not detailed enough for us beginners.

Answer (score 2):

The current quickly toolkit on 12.04 uses Gtk from gi.repository not the older gtk.
The tutorial has not been updated for this change.

This may be a/your sticking point.

Output `cat SimplePlayerWindow.py`
snip

```
from gi.repository import Gtk # pylint: disable=E0611
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('simple_player')
```

/snip

Comment: Skimming through that page, I see alot of references to just gtk and gtk.gdk, so this is probably not the case.

Comment: @Timo fair point, see the edit